# HTML CSS PHP, Table design

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

i have a problem to create table like this image in website, can anyone help me to solve that?.  blue line in picture. i just don't know how to create table like this image. especially reference no, it has custom border line.
[Here is table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K7bL.png)

you can check my code here too [MY CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/uubwqnf3/3/)

this is my code

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/ifxhtml">
    <head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">

        <title>Glisten - A free web template</title>



    </head>
    <body>



<table width="800" border="1" align="center">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor=""><table width="800" border="1" align="center">
      <tbody>

        <tr>
          <td width="125">Reference No</td>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#8B8A8A" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#FF0004"><strong>NG TINEM</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Site ID</td>
          <td colspan="3" align="center"></td>
          <td width="185">BSC Name</td>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Site Name</td>
          <td colspan="3" align="center"></td>
          <td>New Site ID</td>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sales Cluster</td>
          <td colspan="3" align="center"></td>
          <td>LAC</td>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ne Type</td>
          <td colspan="3" align="center"></td>
          <td>Config</td>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Band</td>
          <td colspan="3" align="center"></td>
          <td>PO Number</td>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell ID</td>
          <td width="80" align="center"></td>
          <td width="82" align="center"></td>
          <td width="80" align="center"></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="7" >&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">Integration Date</td>
          <td align="center"></td>
          <td align="center">On Air Date</td>
          <td align="center"></td>
          <td align="center">Acceptance Date</td>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

</tbody>
</table>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: you're gonna have to put better code first

Comment: `width="800" border="12" align="center"` are all presentational attributes and are deprecated in HTML4, let alone HTML5. You should be using CSS.

Comment: Do you have the link to where that webpage was? You can try viewing the source of it with "Ctrl-U" or "F12" in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

First identify the total columns to be created.
Then use attribute of table like "colspan" to span the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Add following style to your table (I have added class `table` in your second table tag):

```
<style type="text/css">
  .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th
  {
        padding: 8px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    vertical-align: top;
  }

  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
    -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
}
</style>


<table width="800" align="center">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor=""><table class="table" width="800" border="1" align="center">
      <tbody>
        <?php
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 
        if($data['dt_report']=='Yes'){
            $check_dt_report='checked="checked"';
        }
        else{
            $check_dt_report='';
        }if($data['kpi_stats']=='Yes'){
            $check_kpi_stats='checked="checked"';
        }
        else{
            $check_kpi_stats='';
        }
        if($data['clear_alarm']=='Yes'){
            $check_clear_alarm='checked="checked"';
        }
        else{
            $check_clear_alarm='';
        }
        if($data['configuration']=='Yes'){
            $check_configuration='checked="checked"';
        }
        else{
            $check_configuration='';
        }
        if($data['neighbor']=='Yes'){
            $check_neighbor='checked="checked"';
        }
        else{
            $check_neighbor='';
        }
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td width="125">Reference No</td>
          <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#8B8A8A" align="center"><?php echo $data['no_ref']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" bgcolor="#FF0004"><strong>NG TINEM</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Site ID</td>
          <td colspan="3" align="center"><?php echo $data['site_id']; ?></td>
          <td width="185">BSC Name</td>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo $data['bsc_name']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Site Name</td>
          <td colspan="3" align="center"><?php echo $data['site_name']; ?></td>
          <td>New Site ID</td>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo $data['new_site_id']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sales Cluster</td>
          <td colspan="3" align="center"><?php echo $data['sales_cluster']; ?></td>
          <td>LAC</td>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo $data['lac']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ne Type</td>
          <td colspan="3" align="center"><?php echo $data['ne_type']; ?></td>
          <td>Config</td>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo $data['config']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Band</td>
          <td colspan="3" align="center"><?php echo $data['band']; ?></td>
          <td>PO Number</td>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo $data['po_number']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell ID</td>
          <td width="80" align="center"><?php echo $data['cell_id1']; ?></td>
          <td width="82" align="center"><?php echo $data['cell_id2']; ?></td>
          <td width="80" align="center"><?php echo $data['cell_id3']; ?></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="7" >&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
</table>
```